# Multiprocessing and while loops in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand how multiprocessing interacts with while loops. I've looked at the documentation and examples, but am having some issues when extending it to my own code.
Suppose I have the following code:

```
def myfunct1():
    x = 0
    while x < 100:
         x += 1
         time.sleep(1)
def myfunct2():
    # arbitrary

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunct1())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunct2())

p1.start()

while p1.isAlive():
     p2.start()
     p2.join()
```

When I run this program, I don't ever reach p2.start(). My current understanding of the code is that p2 should run and finish continuously while p1 is still active, and should stop doing so when p1 finishes. Is there something that I'm missing?

My computer is dual-core, if that matters.

Comment: `target=myfunct1()` => `target=myfunct1` or you're passing the _result_ of the function instead of the function itself

Comment: Your `p1` is not assigned to until `myfunct1()` completes processing, as you assigned the *result* of the function, not the function itself (so `None` here). Same for `p2`. As such, without a target `p1` is never alive.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: found one that applies to multiprocessing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I had a dollar every time someone gets tricked by this ... I have added my answer (which applies to threads & processing). Thanks for changing to dupe. When are the next mod elections so I can vote for you ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: moderators are elected for life; I've jumped that gauntlet already! Thanks for the vote of confidence though. :-)